# Apply visual studio theme (Light/Dark) for wpf popup dialogs

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, themes, wpf-controls

I am developing visual studio extension which consist of ToolWindowPane (inside this  I have grideview and several other controls). Apart from this, I have message dialog(s), and file upload dialog(s) in this extension. I was able to successfully inherit Microsoft themes(Light/Dark) which dynamically changes with visual-studio settings for ToolWindowPane and controls inside it. But it looks like these themes does not applies for dialog boxes.

Is there any way to apply VS themes for dialog boxes?  It would be great help if someone could show some guidance on this. Example / tutorial would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The styling of dialog boxes comes from the OS. Visual Studio has no control over their styling.